# Filling Pressurised Cartridge with valve?

Tags: pressure, air

I have a standart compressor rated up to 8 bars, using it for painting, cleaning, pumping up wheels, etc. I now want to make a little backyard project, essentially a super-powered super soaker, which uses pressure cartridges to provide the pressure. Online I've found some that are rated up to 200 bar, and of course that would be way better than 8. So I wonder wether I can fill this up with my comnpressor using a valve, essentially putting air in that can't flow back. Would a valve allow me to keep the air inside the cartridge, while the compressor keeps on pumping in more and more, or would the air leak back, making it so both systems have the same pressure? I don't really have much experience in that regard, so any tips might be helpful. If I can't use a valve, are there any other ways I can increase the pressure in the cartridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any cryogenic handling equipment lying around? If the cartridge were filled with either extremely cold gas or liquefied air, its pressure will increase as it warms to the ambient temperature. This would allow you to achieve high pressure in the cartridge, while the filling/transfer process occurs at much lower pressure.

I doubt this proposal will help you very much, what with requiring some fairly specialised equipment!

Please also consider using a variable inline regulator on your superdupersoaker; 200 bar is rather a lot for something that will presumably be aimed at a human being. A first-cut calculation with Bernoulli's equation suggests the water would exit at around 200 m/s!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And to put your worries to rest, I won't use this thing on any living beings. I just want to build it for the fun of building such a thing, not for actual use in water-combat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 120 psi maximum air compressor you cannot put more than 120 psi of air pressure into a storage tank without a way of further compressing the air. When you have 120 psi inside the tank and 120 psi at the inlet tube, they are at equilibrium and air will not flow. Any one way valves would not change this.